# Cómo puedo actualizar un proyecto de Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Debo trabaja en un proyecto de Flutter previamente hecho, es decir, alguien más lo hizo y yo debo continuar. El problema es que es un proyecto de hace varios años hecho con Flutter 2.12.0 y actualmente tengo la versión 3.16.5

Al clonar de GitHub el proyecto a mi versión actual aparecen muchos errores debido a las dependencias que han sido actualizadas. Lo que he intentado es:

- Intentar hacer correr la app con mis versiones actuales.
- Actualizar las dependencias una por una.
- Regresar a la versión de Flutter 2.12.0 con la que el proyecto fue inicialmente creado, así como ajustar una versión de Java y Gradle que fuesen compatibles.
- Actualizar las dependencias con flutter pub upgrade.

Nada me ha permitido hacer que la app pueda correr. Agradecería bastante que alguien me diga cómo solucionar esto.

Gracias.

Comment: Sí el proyecto funcionaba antes de cogerlo tú, con usar la versión de Flutter con la que se desarrolló el proyecto, debería ser más que suficiente, no deberías tocar nada más de las dependencias.

Comment: tienes 2 opciones, la primera bajar la versión de flutter que tienes instalada actualmente(para nada recomendable) o la segunda, en la que tienes que actualizar los paquetes que use este proyecto con un "flutter pub upgrade --major-versions", ver la documentación de cada paquete e ir actualizandolos manualmente(la más recomendable). Obviamente te aconsejo la 2da, ya que actualizaciones seguiran saliendo y es mejor tener una aplicación actualizada con las versiones más recientes.